# I need to represent this hibernate table to mysql table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
@Entity
public class Domain {

    @Id
    private long id;

    /** The parent domain, can be null if this is the root domain. */
    @ManyToOne
    private Domain parent;

    /**
     * The children domain of this domain.
     *
     * This is the inverse side of the parent relation.
     *
     * <strong>It is the children responsibility to manage there parents children set!</strong>
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Domain> children = new HashSet<Domain>();
```

I know how to create table like:
Create table domain(id int(10),and so on,but I dont understand how to insert Domain parent. 
And generally i need help in tree application,where need to represent relationsip parent-child

Comment: Look up many-to-one relationships and join columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a normal relationship between tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE DOMAIN
  (
     id        BIGINT auto_increment,
     -- other..
     parent_id BIGINT
  );

ALTER TABLE DOMAIN
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES DOMAIN(id);
```